# Problem injecting a service into a component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

When I try to inject a Service into my Component Angular won't load the component and throws an error instead. The error in the console just says:

```
ERROR Error: "[object Object]"
    Angular 11
        resolvePromise
        resolvePromise
        scheduleResolveOrReject
        invokeTask
        onInvokeTask
        invokeTask
        runTask
        drainMicroTaskQueue
        invokeTask
        invokeTask
        globalZoneAwareCallback
```

The component I'm trying to inject the service into (it is the workout-service):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { CalendarService } from '../shared/calendar.service';
import { WorkoutService } from '../shared/workout.service';
import { Set } from '../shared/set.model';
import { Exercise } from '../shared/exercise.model';
import { Workout } from '../shared/workout.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-workout-form',
  templateUrl: './workout-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./workout-form.component.css']
})
export class WorkoutFormComponent implements OnInit {
  exerciseArr: number[] = [];

  selectedDay = '1';
  selectedMonth = 'Mai';
  selectedYear = '2019';

  constructor(public calendarService: CalendarService, private workoutService: WorkoutService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
[...]
```

And here is the service that I'm trying to inject:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WorkoutService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private authService: AuthService) { }

  saveWorkoutToDb(workout) {
    this.http.post([...]);
  }
}
```

My IDE gave me the error message that it can't resolve all parameters for the given component. When I remove the injection, the component gets loaded fine.

This is my app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatCardModule,  MatInputModule, MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { WorkoutFormComponent } from './workout-form/workout-form.component';
import { WorkoutCalendarComponent } from './workout-calendar/workout-calendar.component';
import { WorkoutEditComponent } from './workout-edit/workout-edit.component';
import { AuthComponent } from './auth/auth.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WorkoutFormComponent,
    WorkoutCalendarComponent,
    WorkoutEditComponent,
    AuthComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Edit: it seems that when I remove the injection of the HttpClient in the workout service, the error disappears.

Comment: Can you inject the service elsewhere, e.g. does it work in your tests?

Comment: Can you show us your `app.module.ts` (the module of the component) ?

Comment: I tried to inject the service in another component and it threw the same error.

Comment: did you miss putting your service in providers array?

Comment: Try to add "HttpClientModule" into imports array in your app.module.ts Also use this import: `import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';`

Comment: That solved it, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your app.module.ts like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatCardModule,  MatInputModule, MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { WorkoutFormComponent } from './workout-form/workout-form.component';
import { WorkoutCalendarComponent } from './workout-calendar/workout-calendar.component';
import { WorkoutEditComponent } from './workout-edit/workout-edit.component';
import { AuthComponent } from './auth/auth.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WorkoutFormComponent,
    WorkoutCalendarComponent,
    WorkoutEditComponent,
    AuthComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    HttpClientModule, //<- you are missing this import 
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: Did you add all the services? You are also using `AuthService` and `CalendarService`

Comment: Yes, even if I add all the services I'm using to the providers array I still get the same error that only appears when I try to load a component in which I inject this workout service.

Comment: Did you miss the fact that the service is declared with `providedIn: 'root'` in the `@Injectable` decorator? That makes adding the service to the module unnecessary. @AsimHashmi

Comment: I just found out that injecting the service works when I remove the injection of the HttpClient into the workout service. Does anyone have an idea what causes this behaviour?

Comment: @R.Richards I didn't notice that as this error is pretty much common and related to not registering service in module. Thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: @fonzane I think your missing the import for `HttpClientModule` in your `app.module.ts`. That's why it throws error when you inject `HttpClient`

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me, you need to add 'HttpClientModule' class to the *imports* in the *app.module.ts* file. Just remember it need to be in the root module, declaring this class in child modules will not work.